# SQL check dates between columns and over rows

Tags: postgresql

How can I write a query to tell me if specified date `(e.g. 2015-01-15)` falls within the range of ANY '`from_date`' '`to_date`' period in the table below? What's special here is that I only want one row per id returned.

```
id | from_date  | to_date
a  | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-30
a  | 2015-04-01 | 2015-04-30
```

Current query:

```
select id,
case when from_date <= '2015-01-15'
     and to_date >= '2015-01-15'
     then 'true' else 'false' end as status
from dates
```

Current result:

```
id | status
a  | true
a  | false
```

Desired result:

```
id | status
a  | true
```

Comment: you can find what you need here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Have you made any attempts at writing this? This is a very basic SQL request. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Regarding Sombriks suggestion, it's a starting point, but what you need is the [BETWEEN](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-between/) operator in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks John, have attempted to improve the example.

Comment: Select x, thing between thing and thing as status from z

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is DISTINCT ON. A DISTINCT ON on the id column outputs only one row per id.

Try the following query,

```
 select distinct on(id) id,
 case when from_date <= '2015-01-15'
 and to_date >= '2015-01-15'
 then 'true' else 'false' end as status from dates;
```

which outputs to,

```
   id | status 
   ----+--------
    a | true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,'true' as status
from dates
where '2015-01-15' between from_date and to_date;
```

Comment: Thanks Cetin. However, I also want to return the id if it's false. So one row per id.